# How can I perform cross platform background HttpClient Post for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to implement a cross platform Upload library for my Xamarin project that can perform background upload to a Rest Api.

I am implementing the iOS client at the moment, and I have selected the HttpClient implementation to be NSUrlSession in Project Settings.

My Upload library implements standard HttpClient methods for syncing. For example (stripped down for simplicity) ...

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload(string url, HttpContent content) {
    return await client.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

Now I would like to implement a background Upload when the user presses a "Finish Button" in the UI. Xamarin offers three backgrounding techniques
[iOS Backgrounding with Tasks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/)

I'm trying to decide whether to use **Background-Safe Tasks** or **Background Transfers (iOS 7+)**, and I was hoping to clarify the following:

- If I choose Background Transfers, am I correct in stating that I'm now tying my Upload Manager to a platform specific implementation, since the Background Transfer is an NSUrlSession feature, and although HttpClient implements NSUrlSession it doesn't implement this type of specific functionality.
- If I choose Background-Safe Tasks, I am spinning up a background task
  and I'm still using NSUrlSession, but my Upload Manager implementation can be cross platform since it's using the HttpClient in a more generic way and not using Background Transfers.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You used to be able to call `BeginBackgroundTask` to let the transfer complete in the background, but that [stopped working](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6443) in a recent Xamarin update.